# Gregorian Calendar

Tags: calendar, gregorian-calendar

One part of my assignment requires me to use gregorian calendar in the student class.

Every student has a unique studentNumber (int), name (String), **

dateRegistered (GregorianCalendar)

** , id (String) and courseEnrolled  (CourseOffering).

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public abstract class Student
{
    private int studentNumber;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private CourseOffering courseEnrolled;
    private GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();

    public Student( int studentNumber, String name, String id, CourseOffering courseEnrolled){
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.courseEnrolled = courseEnrolled;
    }

    public int getStudentNumber(){
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%08d", studentNumber) + "          " + name + "     " + id;
    }

}
```

I wasn't taught on how to use the calendar in school yet, but this came up for the assignment.

"The constructor that does all the necessary initializations given all necessary values including the day (int), month (int) and year (int) of the registration date "

How do i put the day month year in the constructor ? Help guys :(

Comment: We're not going to do your homework, but if you google `java 8 gregoriancalendar api`, you'll get [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) which basically tells you everything you need to know. If you don't know how a `class` works, google `java 8 myclass api`.

Comment: well i wasnt asking for anyone to do my homework for me ? i was just listing out the requirements of this small part of my assignment so that people reading this could have a better understanding of what i am trying to ask. and there thats what i needed, some information of or guideline to 'learn more about' the gregorian calendar.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I jumped to conclusions. Go here, and find the constructor you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar--

Comment: I've read about that, but dont really understand how it actually works.
do i create another constructor for it like this ?

public Student( int studentNumber, String name, String id, CourseOffering courseEnrolled){
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.courseEnrolled = courseEnrolled;
    }

    public Student(int year,int month,int dayOfMonth){
        startDate = new GregorianCalendar(year,  month, dayOfMonth);
    }

Comment: It should be  startDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, dayOfMonth)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 )  // January 23, 2018.
```

Use *java.time* classes instead. Unlike the legacy classes, these modern classes use sane numbering:

- `2018` is year 2018.
- 1-12 for January-December.
- 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

The *java.time* classes use static factory methods rather than `new` constructor calls.

## `ZonedDateTime`

The `GregorianCalendar` class is now obsolete (good riddance). Replaced by `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime  zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 18 , 30 ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
    )
;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-01-23T18:30+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).